# scorm quiz fetch questions from a json file

Tags: jquery, html, scorm

I have created a simple quiz system with HTML and jQuery. It's a one page sliding template. The questions are fetched from a json file and showed in the HTML by jQuery. As simple as this.
Now I want to add this to the scorm cloud. I need help doing that. I have copied the manifest file from another project and edited. Then I zipped the whole project folder and uploaded into scorm cloud. Uploading was a success, but now when I tried to test it, I don't get the questions although I included the questions.json file.
**Script for fetching questions:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'questions.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        encoding: 'UTF-8'
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        var result_array = $.map(result, function(el) { return el; });
        result_array = shuffle(result_array);
        result_array = result_array.slice(0, 15); 

        var json_string = JSON.stringify(result_array);
        var questionsReadyForStorage = encodeURIComponent(json_string);
        localStorage.setItem('questions', questionsReadyForStorage);
        QUESTIONS = localStorage.getItem('questions');
        QUESTIONS = decodeURIComponent(QUESTIONS);
        QUESTIONS = JSON.parse(QUESTIONS);
        set_question(0);
    })  
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: '+textStatus);
        do_sliding(false, '#start', false, true);
    });
```

Here I get the ajax error. Can't fetch the questions. I have also tried using an external url for fetching the questions.json file in ajax call, but no luck. Is my approach wrong here? How can I do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Its not coming to the done. Its coming to error. means the ajax call was not success.

Comment: Is it getting to the line ".error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) "? What are the values of those parameters?

Comment: It actually cannot find the file 'questions.json'. So I get 404 error. But the file is there actually.

Comment: Can you tell me the paths of the questions.json file and the file that contains this code? What happens if you navigate there directly?